# Using QueryList gives the first HTML element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10, viewchild, viewchildren

I'm using Angular 10, and trying to use QueryList, with the code below (just like many examples on the web)

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]" #someID>some content</div>
```

TS

```
  @ViewChild('someID') someIds: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

When running console.log(this.someIds) in the component, after the component initialization, I'm actually getting an ElementRef object (probably the first or the last div) and not the whole list.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change ` @ViewChild('someID')` to ` @ViewChildren('someID')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change **ViewChild** to **ViewChildren**

```
@ViewChildren('someID') someIds: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```